# How to Multiply elements in a list and add those which is inside another list

Tags: python

I have a list which looks like this

```
a= [[1, 0.4], [0, 0.5], [0, 0.9], [0, 0.3], [0, 0.6], [1, 0.1], [1,
0.9], [1, 0.8]]
```

on this I want to do a mathematical calculation like

```
(1*0.4) + (0*0.5)
+ (0*0.9)+.....+(1*0.8)
```

(multiplying elements in the sublist and then add the result)

my code is:

```
for i in a:
    s=0
    z=i[0][0]*i[0][1]
    s+=z
print(s)
```

But I am getting 'int' object is not subscriptable error. But ideally    `a[0][0] * a[0][1]` is giving correct result outside the loop.

Comment: You're not multiplying the elements? You're concatenating them from what I see in your example

Comment: i is already an element of a

Answer (score 4):

In your example there were two errors:

1. You were setting `s` to zero within the for loop, it should be set before the for loop. If you set it within the loop, the sum gets set to zero every time you iterate the for loop/multiply a pair of numbers and hence it would just return the last calculation `1 * 0.8`
2. when you use `i in a` it loops through each element in a. For instance, the first loop `i` will be `[1, 0.4]`. When you do `i[0]` it returns the first element of `i`, `1`, which is an int. You are then trying to subcript `i` again with `i[0][0]` hence the error `'int' object is not subscriptable`

given this you can rewrite your code as:

```
s=0
for i in a: # i is each element in a, one at a time, in order
    z=i[0]*i[1] # take the first number in i and multiply by the second number
    s+=z # add to the sum
print(s)
```

output:

```
2.2
```

You could also do it in one line with list comprehension:

Multiply the pairs together and then take the sum

```
sum([x[0] * x[1] for x in a])
```

output:

```
2.2
```

Comment: This is a great pythonic way of doing what the OP asked. However you didn't really help them see why their code didn't work. Still +1.

Comment: @Mythalorian I just edited my answer to go through his code to explain it further

Comment: Very well put together. This should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will just toss this little bit more beginner friendly solution:

```
res = 0 # declaring result outside of the loop so it does not get restarted
for e in a: # e is in this case the element of the list not list it self
    res += e[0] * e[1] # multiplying and adding to res
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below code :

```
new_list=[]
for i in a:
    new_list.append(i[0]*i[1])
sum(new_list)
new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to subscript an `int`.

`i` is a list and `i[0]` is an `int`. Now you are subscripting an `int` with this statement `i[0][0]`.

That's the reason you get- *'int' object is not subscriptable error*

Correct Code should be:

```py
for i in a:
    s += i[0] * i[1]
print(s)
```